Next.js with --experimental-https, FastAPI calls coming back with "Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request"
For a couple of reasons, I need to be testing locally with https instead of http, so I've been trying to get my Next.js frontend talking to my FastAPI backend. I'm running next.js with --experimental-https, and I'm making a get request to http://localhost:3100/retrieve-prices and http://localhost:3100/get-subscription using Axios.
In browser, I get two different errors:
GET https://localhost:3100/retrieve-prices net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
and
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3100/get-subscription' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
The only thing different between those is that get-subscription uses a Authorization header with a Bearer token.
In the network tab, this is the output for the retrieve-prices call:
Request URL: http://localhost:3100/retrieve-prices
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: Cross-Origin
Location: https://localhost:3100/retrieve-prices
Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS

There's a second retrieve-prices entry too, that shows:
Request URL: https://localhost:3100/retrieve-prices
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

The get-subscription call shows this, but nothing else useful:
Request URL: http://localhost:3100/get-subscription
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

On my FastAPI code, I tried setting origins and removing the HTTPSRedirectMiddleware:
app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

origins = ["http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

app.remove_middleware(HTTPSRedirectMiddleware)
app.remove_middleware(TrustedHostMiddleware)

But that unfortunately didn't work.
I do realize I can use tunnels or a custom cert to get around this whole issue, but for a couple of reasons that make those solutions difficult, I'm hoping there's a simple Next.js or FastAPI setting I can change for development that will allow these connections. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
